# How have a build store using maven (new build timestamped folder and latest folder)?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3

I want to create a new folder at every build, when I build the project using Maven.

Below my requirements:

1. Create jar-files for every module of project.
2. Create folder for new build with name like **build_'current-date-with-time'** in some external directory
3. Copy jar-files to **build_'current-date-with-time'/libs**
4. Copy configuration files to **build_'current-date-with-time'/conf**
5. Copy all this also to **latest** folder (files in this folder will be changed to latest build)

**Questions**:

- How to add 'current-date-with-time' to build path?
- How to move jars to external folder?
- How also move other file to this folders and how move all this files once again to one another folder?

Comment: Why do you like to do such thing? Why copying jars to libs folder ? What kind of project do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to accomplish it:

- Use the maven `${maven.build.timestamp}` property as directory name suffix to have dynamic directory names with timestamp
- Redefine the `maven.build.timestamp.format`, if required, to remove the `:` default character which may cause issues in some OS. For example, to the value `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss` (the `_` replaces `:`)
- Configure the `maven-clean-plugin` to clean up the `latest` folder before executing this build activity. The official documentation already provides an example of [how to delete additional files](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html)
- Configure the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy your project resources to the `latest` and the new build store folder, via two different plugin executions. The official documentation already provides an example on [how to copy resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)
- Configure the `maven-jar-plugin` to package project artifacts to the two directories (latest and build), I would recommend with two different maven `classifier` (the timestamp and `latest` are perfect candidates). The official documentation alread provides example on [how to attach additional jars](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html)
- Configure the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy project dependencies to the two folders, via two plugin executions. The official documentation already provides an example on [how to copy project dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html)
- Place this whole build configuration in a Maven [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in order not to have it as default behavior yet able to invoke it on demand

Here is a full implementation of the above, already placed in a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>build-store</id>

    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <build.store.directory>c:\build_${maven.build.timestamp}</build.store.directory>
        <build.store.directory.latest>c:\latest</build.store.directory.latest>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${build.store.directory.latest}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-build-store</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <classifier>${maven.build.timestamp}</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-latest</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory.latest}</outputDirectory>
                            <classifier>latest</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-build-store</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies-to-latest</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory.latest}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-build-store</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory}/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-latest</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${build.store.directory.latest}/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Invoking the build via:

```
mvn clean package -P build-store
```

Would then clean up the `latest` folder content, create a new folder based on the build timestamp, move the required files to it and to the `latest` folder.

You can define the destination folders editing the `build.store.directory` and `build.store.directory.latest` properties.

Additional improvements and configuration can then easily added to this profile, according to further requirements.